# Align vuetify tabs vertically on the right hand side

Tags: vuetify.js

The `vertical` prop in vuetify aligns tabs on the left hand side. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-vertical

How do I align tabs on the right hand side? The `right` prop doesn't seem to work with `vertical`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only prop you need to pass to the component is `vertical`, and the aligning can be done in css:

```
<template>
  <v-tabs vertical>
    <v-tab>Tab One</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Tab Two</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Tab Three</v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<style>
.v-tabs--vertical {
  align-items: end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.v-tabs-slider-wrapper {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

in Vuetify 3:

```
<template>
   <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
    <v-tabs direction="vertical" >
     <v-tab>Tab One</v-tab>
     <v-tab >Tab Two</v-tab>
     <v-tab>Tab Three</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
   </div>
 </template>

<style>
  .v-tab__slider {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Vuetify 2 here but probably in Vuetify 3 one can use the same approach, you need to add `vertical` property to `<v-tabs>` and a bit of css. Use `::v-deep` to access `.v-tabs-bar` and `.v-window` classes

```html
<template>
  <v-tabs vertical>
    <v-tab>One</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Two</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Three</v-tab>
    <v-tab-item>First item</v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>Second item</v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>Third item</v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<style>
.v-tabs.v-tabs--vertical {
  flex-direction: row;
}

::v-deep .v-tabs--vertical > .v-tabs-bar {
  order: 2;
}

::v-deep .v-tabs--vertical > .v-window {
  order: 1;
}
</style>
```